# Run cp command from frida script

Tags: javascript, android, frida

Im running a Frida script injecting into app eg.

```
frida -U -f com.myapp.example -l myscript.js --no-pause
```

How do I execute console commands eg. launch `cp` from Frida Javascript? My script  `myscript.js` would be like :

```
var createPtr = Module.findExportByName(null, 'create');

Interceptor.replace(createPtr, new NativeCallback( function (a){
    //execute cp command here eg. cp a "/out/path"
    return 1;
    }, 'int', ['pointer']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap libc functions to read & write to file using the following example that gets thread's name by tid

```js
const fopen = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName('libc.so', 'fopen'), 'pointer', ['pointer', 'pointer']);
const fclose = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName('libc.so', 'fclose'), 'int', ['pointer']);
const getc = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName('libc.so', 'getc'), 'int', ['pointer']);

function getThreadName(tId) {
  var name = new Array(20);
  var f = fopen(Memory.allocUtf8String('/proc/self/task/' + tId + '/comm'), MODE_READ);
  var c, i = 0;
  while (i < name.length) {
    var c = getc(f);
    name[i++] = String.fromCharCode(c != -1 && c != 10 ? c : 32);
  }
  fclose(f);
  name = name.join('')
  return name;
}
```

but you should wrap your code with python

```js
import frida
from frida_tools.application import Reactor
import threading
import click


class Shell(object):
    def __init__(self, argv, env):
        self._stop_requested = threading.Event()
        self._reactor = Reactor(run_until_return=lambda reactor: self._stop_requested.wait())

        self._device = frida.get_usb_device()
        self._sessions = set()

        self._device.on("child-added", lambda child: self._reactor.schedule(lambda: self._on_child_added(child)))
        self._device.on("child-removed", lambda child: self._reactor.schedule(lambda: self._on_child_removed(child)))
        self._device.on("output", lambda pid, fd, data: self._reactor.schedule(lambda: self._on_output(pid, fd, data)))

        self.argv = argv
        self.env = env
        self.output = []  # stdout will pushed into array

    def exec(self):
        self._reactor.schedule(lambda: self._start())
        self._reactor.run()

    def _start(self):
        click.secho("✔ spawn(argv={})".format(self.argv), fg='green', dim=True)
        pid = self._device.spawn(self.argv, env=self.env, stdio='pipe')
        self._instrument(pid)

    def _stop_if_idle(self):
        if len(self._sessions) == 0:
            self._stop_requested.set()

    def _instrument(self, pid):
        click.secho("✔ attach(pid={})".format(pid), fg='green', dim=True)
        session = self._device.attach(pid)
        session.on("detached", lambda reason: self._reactor.schedule(lambda: self._on_detached(pid, session, reason)))
        click.secho("✔ enable_child_gating()", fg='green', dim=True)
        session.enable_child_gating()
        # print("✔ resume(pid={})".format(pid))
        self._device.resume(pid)
        self._sessions.add(session)

    def _on_child_added(self, child):
        click.secho("⚡ child_added: {}".format(child), fg='green', dim=True)
        self._instrument(child.pid)

    @staticmethod
    def _on_child_removed(child):
        click.secho("⚡ child_removed: {}".format(child), fg='green', dim=True)

    def _on_output(self, pid, fd, data):
        # print("⚡ output: pid={}, fd={}, data={}".format(pid, fd, repr(data)))
        # fd=0 (input) fd=1(stdout) fd=2(stderr)
        if fd != 2:
            self.output.append(data)

    def _on_detached(self, pid, session, reason):
        click.secho("⚡ detached: pid={}, reason='{}'".format(pid, reason), fg='green', dim=True)
        self._sessions.remove(session)
        self._reactor.schedule(self._stop_if_idle, delay=0.5)

    @staticmethod
    def _on_message(pid, message):
        click.secho("⚡ message: pid={}, payload={}".format(pid, message), fg='green', dim=True)
```

```py
cmd = Shell(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'cp /data/data/com.app/databases/a.db /data/local/tmp'], None)
cmd.exec()
with open('/tmp/example', 'wb+') as f:
    f.writelines(cmd.output)
```

Comment: MODE_READ isn't defined anywhere. Can define it as `Memory.allocUtf8String('r')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following JS code to your script use it from within your function.

```
function copyfile(source, destination) {
    const File = Java.use('java.io.File');
    const FileInputStream = Java.use('java.io.FileInputStream');
    const FileOutputStream = Java.use('java.io.FileOutputStream');
    const BufferedInputStream = Java.use('java.io.BufferedInputStream');
    const BufferedOutputStream = Java.use('java.io.BufferedOutputStream');
    var sourceFile = File.$new.overload('java.lang.String').call(File, source);
    if (sourceFile.exists() && sourceFile.canRead()) {
        var destinationFile = File.$new.overload('java.lang.String').call(File, destination);
        destinationFile.createNewFile();
        var fileInputStream = FileInputStream.$new.overload('java.io.File').call(FileInputStream, sourceFile);
        var fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream.$new.overload('java.io.File').call(FileOutputStream, destinationFile);
        var bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream.$new.overload('java.io.InputStream').call(BufferedInputStream, fileInputStream);
        var bufferedOutputStream = BufferedOutputStream.$new.overload('java.io.OutputStream').call(BufferedOutputStream, fileOutputStream);
        var data = 0;
        while ((data = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            bufferedOutputStream.write(data);
        }
        console.log('[*] Finished copying to : ' + destination);
        bufferedInputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
    else {
        console.log('[!] Error : File cannot read.')
    }
}

var createPtr = Module.findExportByName(null, 'create');

Interceptor.replace(createPtr, new NativeCallback( function (a){
    //execute cp command here eg. cp a "/out/path"
    copyfile(a, "/out/path");
    return 1;
}, 'int', ['pointer']));
```